Does $[K_1K_2:F]\le[K_1:F][K_2:F]$ also hold for infinite extensions?
If $K/F$ is a field extensions, $K_1,K_2$ are intermediate fields for which $K_1/F$ and $K_2/F$ are finite extensions and $K_1K_2=F(K_1\cup K_2)$ is their composition, then we have
$$[K_1K_2:F]\le[K_1:F][K_2:F]$$
(This is Proposition 21 of Dummit & Foote, Abstract Algebra, Wiley, 2004.) Does this also hold if either $K_1/F$ or $K_2/F$ is an infinite extension? My proof for the case of finite extensions is as follows. Suppose $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_m$ and $\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n$ are bases of $K_1$ and $K_2$ respectively over $K$. Then clearly we have
$$K_1K_2=F(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_m,\beta_1,\dots,\beta_m).$$
Since $K_1/F$ and $K_2/F$ are finite extensions, they are algebraic extensions, hence the $\alpha_i$ and the $\beta_j$ are algebraic over $F$. Hence
$$\begin{align}
K_1K_2 & = F(\alpha_1)\cdots(\alpha_m)(\beta_1)\cdots(\beta_n) \\
& = F[\alpha_1]\cdots[\alpha_m][\beta_1]\cdots[\beta_n] \\
& = F[\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_m,\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n] 
\end{align}
$$
Finally, for every polynomial $f\in F[x_1,\dots,x_m,y_1,\dots,y_n]$, $f(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_m,\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n)$ is a linear combination of the $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_j$ over $F$. Indeed, a product of powers of the $\alpha_i$ is in $K_1$, hence a linear combination of $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_m$. For the same reason, a product of powers of the $\beta_j$ is a linear combination of $\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n$. This will represent $f(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_m,\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n)$ as a linear combination of the $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_j$. The proof is complete.
But if either $K_1/F$ or $K_2/F$ is an infinite extension, then they may not be algebraic nor finitely generated, so my proof does not apply. Any help will be appreciated!
Edit: I should have mentioned that here the degree $[L:K]$ of an extension is defined as a cardinal number which is the dimension of the vector space $L$ over $K$. Otherwise, as ultralegend5385 have pointed out, the answer is trivially yes.

First, assume that $K_1K_2$ is algebraic over $F$. If $\kappa_0,\kappa_1$ are infinite cardinals, then $\kappa_0\cdot\kappa_1=\max(\kappa_0,\kappa_1)$. If $(\alpha_i)_{i\in\kappa_0}$ and $(\beta_j)_{j\in\kappa_1}$ are bases for $K_1$ respectively $K_2$ over $F$, then $(\alpha_i\cdot\beta_j)_{(i,j)\in\kappa_0\times\kappa_1}$ is a generating system for $K_1K_2$ over $F$.
In general now, we have the claim: If $K$ is not algebraic over $F$, then $[K:F]=|K|$ where $|I|$ denotes the cardinality of a set $I$.
Proof: We can assume that $K=F((x_i)_{i\in I})$ since there is a purely transcendental intermediate extension $F\subseteq E\subseteq K$ such that $K$ is algebraic over $E$ and as $E$ is infinite, we have $|E|=|K|$ (this requires an argument) and $[E:F]\leq [K:F]$.
Now, $[F((x_i)_{i\in I}):F]\geq\max(|F|,|I|,\aleph_0)$. First, $[F[(x_i)_{i\in I}]:F]\geq \max(|I|,\aleph_0)$.
Note that $\left\{\frac{1}{1+fx}\mid f\in F\right\}$ is a linearly independent set in $F(x)$ over $F$ (this requires some non-trivial argument, see below). Thus $[F((x_i)_{i\in I}]:F] \geq |F|$.
On the other hand, $|F((x_i)_{i\in I})|\leq\max(|F|,|I|,\aleph_0)$ by counting all rational functions in $F((x_i)_{i\in I})$, thus the claim follows as $|F((x_i)_{i\in I})|\geq [F((x_i)_{i\in I}):F]$.
If $K_1K_2$ is not algebraic over $F$, then also $K_1$ or $K_2$ is not algebraic over $F$. Thus, $|K_1K_2|=|K_1||K_2|$, since every element in $K_1K_2$ is a fraction of elements of the form $\sum k^1_ik^2_i$ with $k_i^j\in K_j$ and one of $K_j$ is infinite. With the claim above we are done.
Why is $\left\{\frac{1}{1+fx}\mid f\in F\right\}$ a linearly independent set in $F(x)$ (over $F$)?
It is sufficient to prove that $\frac{1}{1+f_ix}$ are linearly independent over $F$ for any pairwise distinct $f_0,...f_{n-1}\in F$. This is equivalent to the fact that the polynomials $p_i=\prod_{j\neq i}(1+f_jx)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a^n_{ik}x^k$ are independent. This follows from the fact that the determinant of $(a^n_{jk})$ is equal to $\prod_{i<j}(f_i-f_j)\neq 0$. To see this last claim, note that if $\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(1+z_ix)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}p^n_i(z_0,...,z_{n-1})x^i$, then $a^n_{ik}=p^n_k(f_0,...,f_{i-1},f_{i+1}...f_n)$ and $p^n_k(z_0,...,z_{n-1})=\sum_{A\in\binom{\{0,...,n-1\}}{k}}\prod_{j\in A}z_j$. Then, $a^n_{ik}-a^n_{(n-1)k}=(f_{n-1}-f_{i})a^{n-1}_{i(k-1)}$. From this the claim follows by induction on $n$.

Thank you very much for the cool and complete answer! I'm reading it now.

Now I understand that the inequality holds for two transcendental extensions. But when $K_1/F$ is algebraic and $K_2/F$ is not, the inequality becomes $|K_1||K_2|\le[K_1:F]|K_2|$. Does the inequality also hold in this case? I know the reversed inequality holds since $[K_1:F]\le|K_1|$ always holds.

If $K_1/F$ is algebraic, then $[K_1:F]\leq|K_1|\leq|F|\aleph_0$, thus $|K_1||K_2|=|K_2|=[K_1:F]|K_2|$.

Got it. Thank you for explaining!

~ Partial answer ~
Let us show $\dim_F(K_1 K_2) \leq \dim_F(K_1) \cdot \dim_F(K_2)$, where $F \subseteq K_i \subseteq K$.
Consider the $F$-subspace $R$ of $K$ generated by the $uv$ for $u \in K_1$, $v \in K_2$. Observe that $R$ is a subring of $K$. When $B_i$ is an $F$-basis of $K_i$, then it is clear that $\{uv : u \in B_1, v \in B_2\}$ is an $F$-generating set of $R$. This shows
$$\dim_F(R) \leq \dim_F(K_1) \cdot \dim_F(K_2).$$
Also, $R$ is the smallest subring of $K$ that contains $K_1$ and $K_2$, so the field of fractions $Q(R)$ is the smallest subfield of $K$ that contains $K_1$ and $K_2$, meaning $Q(R) = K_1 K_2$. So it suffices to estimate $\dim_F(Q(R))$.
If $K_1$ and $K_2$ are algebraic over $F$, then $R$ consists of algebraic elements, and we have $Q(R) = R$. In particular, we are done when $K_1$ and $K_2$ are finite over $F$ (as a vector space).
Assume that $K_1$ or $K_2$ is infinite over $F$. Since $R$ contains both, we conclude that $R$ is also infinite over $F$. The result now follows from the following lemma - under an additional assumption.
Claim. Let $R$ be an integral domain with a countable subfield $F$ such that $R$ is infinite over $F$. Then, $\dim_F(R) = \dim_F(Q(R))$.
Proof. Since $R \subseteq Q(R)$, we have $\dim_F(R) \leq \dim_F(Q(R))$, it remains to show the other direction.
Since $F$ is countable, the dimension of any infinite-dimensional $F$-vector space is just its cardinality. Thus, $\dim_F(Q(R)) = |Q(R)| \leq |R \times R| = |R| = \dim_R(F)$, and we are done.
If $F$ is uncountable, unfortunately the claim doesn't hold.

Thank you so much! I haven't finished reading it yet; maybe I'll have a few questions to ask. Thanks again, it's a great answer.

The last claim should be false as $dim_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathbb{R}[x])$ is countable, but the set ${\frac{1}{1+rx}\mid r\in \mathbb{R}}$ is independent over $\mathbb{R}$ (see my answer). (By the way hi Martin (I know you from ms).)

Ah yes then let me add for clarity that it holds when F is countable.

As mentioned, for an infinite dimensional vector space over a countable field the dimension is equal to the cardinality. Your equation is not correct. Remember that we only have finite linear combinations.

Oh yes! I don't know why but I included in infinite linear combinations. The correct version of my equation should be $|F|^{\oplus\dim_F(Q(R))}$, which equals $\dim_F(Q(R))$ when $F$ is countable and the dimension is infinite. Thanks for explanation!
